# $_POST with klein.php router: How to pass $_POST to a view?

Tags: php, forms, routes, url-routing, klein-mvc

Fishing in uncharted waters, I gave [klein.php](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php) routing a spin and can't for the life of me find out how to pass a $_POST from a html form to another view.

**Example:**

**index.php**

```
<?php
//START ROUTING
require 'klein.php';
require 'autoload.php';

respond('/', function ($request, $response) {
    $response->render('homepage.php', array(
        'meta_title' => 'My Homepage'
    ));
});
respond('/[:name]', function ($request, $response) {
    $response->render('siteinfo.php', array(
        'meta_title' => 'My Details Page'
        ));
});
```

Now, I have a form on **homepage.php** where I do the following:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="url">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

siteinfo.php grabs whatever is passed after the url (i.e. example.com/product123 -> product123) and displays information about that in the view "siteinfo.php". So far this works perfectly with the above code if entered manually into the address bar, since I can access [:name] as $request->name on siteinfo.php.

Whenever I trigger a search on the form, I'd like to pass the $_POST from the homepage.php view to index.php as [:name] without $_GET! Any idea how this works with klein.php or where I should start looking for answers?

I have tried to pass the param() value too, but this still does not work with the form. I have also tried adding action=index.php/siteinfo.php/homepage.php as the form's action, but still no love...

Any help much apprechiated ...

Comment: Don't you need a respond('POST' ...?

Comment: yes, but how and where? what do I need to pass in the form so it'll be correctly routed to index.php as example.com/product123 ?

Comment: still looking for an answer. anybody?

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good place to start.  What have you tried so far?

```
respond('POST', '/', function ($request, $response) {

    $request->validate('url')->notNull();

    $response->url= $request->url;

    $response->render('homepage.php');
});
```